# How to enable "find content" for a role in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I created a role called "Writer".   When a writer logs into the system, they have the black toolbar across the top of the page.   They have the "add content" link which is great.  How do I enable the "find content" link for a writer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to admin/people/permissions and enable "Access the content overview page "